# Cannot load library jniflandmark.dll

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to load the library.
that's works fine for many tested libraries.

But I can't do it with **jniflandmark.dll** library:
Using that code:

```
public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        try
        {
            System.load("C:\\$ Flandmark Libs\\flandmark-1.07-1.1-windows-x86 (1)\\org\\bytedeco\\javacpp\\windows-x86\\jniflandmark.dll");
            System.out.println("Lib is loaded");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            //System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I got that exception:

```
Native code library failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
C:\$ Flandmark Libs\flandmark-1.07-1.1-windows-x86
(1)\org\bytedeco\javacpp\windows-x86\jniflandmark.dll: Can't load IA
32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot load 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit JDK. Either use 64-bit binaries for flandmark, or use a 32-bit version of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please ensure you meet all requirements for installation:
Verify model does not support AVX instructions sets.See [hardware requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#hardware-requirements)
Make sure to download the latest [microsoft visual c++ redistributable from here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)
.Also, please follow the instructions from to install from Tensorflow website.
Please, check Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits?
You may refer to this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36167)

Thanks.